# Where to ask questions about TV configuration?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have a problem with Bravia non-android smart tv with subtitle encoding(`UTF-8` & `UTF-16`).

Which Stack Exchange site would be perfect for this question?

Comment: Is it about programming?

Comment: No @yivi just about settings.

Comment: Then perhaps Super User. There is no dedicated home appliance software site in the network.

Comment: https://superuser.com have questions related to [smart tv](https://superuser.com/search?q=bravia). You would need to look in their help center and form the question

Comment: No, this is not on-topic for Super User either. The [off-topic subjects list](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic) includes "electronic devices, media players, cell phones or smart phones, except insofar as they interface with your computer,"

Comment: @SurajRao: hrm, but *Questions regarding the functionality and usage of TVs to watch broadcast programmes are off-topic.*, according to the [Super user `tv` tag description](https://superuser.com/tags/tv/info). So *maybe* but your mileage may vary.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Ah. Right. This one won't be on topic there either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Nowhere" is likely the correct answer.  The Stack Exchange network doesn't really cover *consumer* electronics in the same way that it does *enthusiast* hardware or software.

Your best bet:  call the manufacturer and ask for support.  If they don't support it, there may be sites out there online (not in the network) which *do* discuss this specific brand of television.

Answer (score -9):

[IoT.SE](https://iot.stackexchange.com) (Internet of Things Stack Exchange) site has [smart-tv tag](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/smart-tv) with few upvoted questions.

I'd say this is your best bet for non android smart TV to ask about its configuration.

Comment: I think this would be stretching the [on-topic](https://iot.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) guidance a bit.

Comment: I really doubt that *subtitles* on a smart tv is going to fall within the topics of IoT